# Docker compose scale with different environment variable value

Tags: docker-compose, containers, environment-variables, scale, gitea

I want to achieve scaling of the container based on the array of values (like a matrix set of values used for creating containers).
I can't do scaling with a single container in docker compose file:

```yml
services:
  runner:
    image: gitea/act_runner:$VERSION
    pull_policy: always
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - "./data/${TOKEN}:/data"
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - GITEA_INSTANCE_URL=https://gitea.self.hosted
      - GITEA_RUNNER_REGISTRATION_TOKEN=$TOKEN
```

Service not allow to create more that one instance with the same token. So I have multiple tokens and based on them creating separate similar containers in docker compose.

Is it possible to create containers based on the amount of the tokens?